# Multiple Authentication Schemes and WWW-Authenticate Challenges

Tags: rest, http, authentication, oauth, oauth-2.0

I am developing a REST API which supports multiple authentication schemes (`OAuth`, `Bearer`, and `Basic`). When the `Authorization` header is absent or contains an unsupported scheme, the service responds with multiple `WWW-Authenticate` headers:

```
WWW-Authenticate: OAuth realm="myRealm"
WWW-Authenticate: Bearer realm="myRealm"
WWW-Authenticate: Basic realm="myRealm"
```

When a request contains an `Authorization` header with one of the supported schemes but invalid credentials, should my service respond with *all* supported `WWW-Authenticate` schemes, or *just* the scheme provided in the request?

For example, if a client provides:

```
Authorization: Bearer invalid
```

Should my service respond with just the `Bearer` challenge?

```
WWW-Authenticate: Bearer realm="myRealm", error="invalid_token", error_description="token is malformed or represents invalid credentials"
```

Or should it respond with all `WWW-Authenticate` challenges?

```
WWW-Authenticate: Bearer realm="myRealm", error="invalid_token", error_description="token is malformed or represents invalid credentials"
WWW-Authenticate: OAuth realm="myRealm"
WWW-Authenticate: Basic realm="myRealm"
```

EDIT: [RFC 7235](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7235#section-4.1) seems to provide a suggestion, although its not concrete. I've added an [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45307985/multiple-authentication-schemes-and-www-authenticate-challenges/45335224#answer-45335224) accordingly.

Comment: Question back: why *not* send all?

Comment: I didn't find any clear guidance in the specs, and adding challenges for other schemes/realms besides the one attempted could confuse callers. That said, I agree, that's not enough reason _not_ to do so. I've added an [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45307985/multiple-authentication-schemes-and-www-authenticate-challenges/45335224#answer-45335224) accordingly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Although it's not strictly required, [RFC 7235](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7235#section-4.1) seems to suggest that *all* supported authentication schemes should be returned. This will provide the most information to callers, provided they are able to parse these headers properly.

> 4.1. WWW-Authenticate
>
> The "WWW-Authenticate" header field indicates the authentication
> scheme(s) and parameters applicable to the target resource.
>
> WWW-Authenticate = 1#challenge
>
> A server generating a 401 (Unauthorized) response MUST send a
> WWW-Authenticate header field containing at least one challenge.  A
> server MAY generate a WWW-Authenticate header field in other response
> messages to indicate that supplying credentials (or different
> credentials) might affect the response.